# Updating ng-show from within .then()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a loader that I show while an async service call is completed, and simply want to hide the loader when complete. Here is my controller:

```
app.controller('DataController', 
  function($scope, DataService) {
    // UI state
    $scope.loading = true;

    DataService.getData({ "count": 10 }).then(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data;

      // UI state
      $scope.loading = false; // does not update ng-view
      $scope.$apply(function() { // generates error
        $scope.loading = false;
      });
    });
});
```

And the view:

```
<div ng-controller="DataController">
  <div id="container">
    <div>
      {{ loading }}
    </div>
    <div class="spinner large" ng-show="loading"></div>
    <div class="data-container" ng-show="!loading">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note the the {{ loading }} value gets updated properly in the view. Using the wrapping `$scope.$apply()` call resulted in an error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog]
```

UPDATE

As this might be promise-related, here's the promise generating `getData()` method from the `DataService` factory:

```
getData: function(params) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  APIService.data(params).then(function(data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

And the last piece, the `APIService.data()` method:

```
data: function(params) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  $resource(endpoint + '/data/feed', {}, {
    'query': { 
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers
    }
  }).query(params).$promise.then(function(data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: You do not need scope.apply. Your issue is else where.. Is this is your full html inside the controller?

Comment: As I stated, tried it without it and the `ng-show` portion of the view did not update - something else I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have an ng-if, ng-something that creates a child scope which  wraps that section? Or is this exactly the way it is?

Comment: Other than changing out proprietary service names/calls, this is it exactly.

Comment: GetData returns angular version of promise right? it shoudl work fine.. check this http://plnkr.co/edit/2PzaPA?p=preview

Comment: @PSL updated with promise-generating code - maybe the problem lies there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue - as this is in a Chrome Extension, I needed to include the Angular CSS CSP file, which includes the `ng-hide` class definition. Including that file resulted in the code working as expected. Thanks everyone for the help. More info:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCsp

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this by binding the show/hide directive to the data-property in the controller. It will be the same as false if the data is undefined.

```
<div class="spinner large" ng-hide="data"></div>
<div class="data-container" ng-show="data">
```

Comment: Good suggestion, spinner not being hidden though.

Comment: Ah, sorry. It should be the other way around. Updated example. Hide element if data property is populated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function() {
  $scope.loading = false;
});
```